# Can't Install Tensorflow 1.14.0 using pip (ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.14.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow 1.14.0

I already updated pip with prompt.

there are some that say that tensorflow does not work with python 3.7

I have already checked that I'm using python 64-bit

I'm using VScode.

this is what I type:

`pip install tensorflow==1.14.0`

this is what shows:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.14.0
```

thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I'm now using Pycharm in another machine and now it is stable.
It seems that I need to verify the VScode later on.

Comment: I encounter the same issue when using python3.8, switch to python3.6 solved my problem.

Comment: try it installing via google colab.
you will be able to install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the answer to this but it seems that VScode that is installed in that computer (computer 1) is unstable.

Now I transferred all my TensorFlow projects to my main computer that runs stable codes.

If I find a definitive answer then I will update this message.

right now the answer is to run in another environment, it worked for me.